# Workflow to - Send Email when Field in List updated SP 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a large list that is used to manage Projects, I want to trigger an email to certain users when a Project Status is changed from "New Project" to "In Assessment" etc.

I've been looking at having two additional columns Previous State and Previous State 2.

1. When a new item is created the Project Status is copied to the Previous State Field.
2. When an item is modified the Previous State value is copied to the Previous State 2 field.
3. If the Project Status and Previous State 2 values don't match an email would be sent.

Would this logic work and how can i avoid an email being sent every time an unrelated field in the list is updated?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an email based on a status field (or any field), you only need to add one field to the list. In your case, add a text field LastProjectStatus (name it whatever). Check to see if the 2 fields are different. If they are, then check for the current status and send the appropriate email. After that, set the 'last' field equal to the current field so the next change that doesn't have anything to do with status won't send the email. We do this all the time - we have complex tasks that have up to 20 status - they move an item between many departments.

Then, in your workflow that runs on a change:

```
If CurrentItem:Project Status not equals CurrentItem:LastProjectStatus
    If(CurrentItem:Project Status equals "In Assessment"
         send an email
    else
      if(CurrentItem:project Status equals "xxx"
         send an email for that
        else if..... etc for each status that needs an email
    then set CurrentItem:LastProjectStatus to CurrentItem:Project Status
```

When I do this, I don't limit it to 'when change from this to that'. I send the email 'when change to that'. Then users can go back and forth with the different statuses, resetting them if they want to go through the whole ting again.

Answer (score 1):

Few questions. Is there some other status than those two you mentioned?
If yes, what if status changes from In assessment to lets say Paused or Non Assigned or something else?
Is it allowed only once for mail to be sent and to notify certain users?

If you need to send only once notification mail, you don't need those two columns. You can manage it with Status column and with additional column **Email sent** type of column Yes/No or choice and than out Yes/No.

Than, when status of your item is changed to **in assessment** trigger workflow to send email and change your status of Column Sent from No to Yes.
In your workflow put first If to check if status **Email sent** is Yes or No. If it is No than go to second If where it should check what is the value of your Project status column and than send an email if that rule is good.

If status of Email send is Yes, than workflow will go to the end and just make a log with some sentance like Email already sent or similar.

Comment: Hi Danilo,

Apologies if I wasn't was clear.

The flow should be like this

1. Project Created in Register - Status is assigned "New Project" - Email sent to stakeholders

2. Project Status changes to "In Assessment" - Email sent to stakeholders 3. Status changes to "Assigned to Owner" - Email sent to stakeholders etc. So any status change should trigger an email to stakeholders but I don't want to send emails if other parts of the list not related to the project status are updated. I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Than add additional If rule beside Status check. Change of values in columns you mentioned are needed to be updated.